# How to add objects into a vector using data from text file

Tags: c++, text, fstream

I have a list of games in a text file as follows:

```
MMO League Of Legends 
MMO World Of Warcraft 
Strategy Civilization 
Strategy Hearthstone 
Arcade Street Fighter 
Arcade PacMan 
AR Beat Saber 
AR Superhot
```

My problem is that I want to create objects using these categories and names, I want to read line by line.

For example, I want to read the first line and when it sees the word MMO to create an MMO object with the name League of legends. Same with the other categories. I already have all the classes and constructors.

Then, I need to save all the objects in the following vector

```
vector <Game*> games;
```

This is my main function so far

```
int main()
{

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("Games.txt");   //Open the file

if (!inFile) {  //Check that file was opened successfully
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    exit(1);
}
string line;
if (inFile.is_open()) {

    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {



    }

}
```

Thanks for your help, I've been working since the morning on this program and this part has truly stumped me!

Comment: This is the 3rd related question you've asked today. I don't recommend learning programming this way.

Comment: Based on previous questions a hierarchy of polymorphic classes is exactly what the OP has.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thats exactly what I have

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to begin by reading line by line into a `std::string` (like you do now). Then you really have two options:

1. Put that string into an [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and extract the first space-delimited word (using the normal `>>` operator) and then `std::getline` to get the remainder of the line into a separate string.
2. [Find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) the first space, and use the [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function to get the first word and the remainder of the line into separate strings.

Once you have your two separate strings you can create the structure using them.

Answer (score 0):

Split the line by the first space:

```
string::size_type pos;
pos=first.find(' ',0);
category=first.substr(0,pos);
name=first.substr(pos+1);
```

Create a new game object with `new` keyword and add it to your vector

```
games.push_back(new Game(category,name))
```

I suppose your Game object has a constructor taking two parameters the categhory and the name